# How do I fix missing type/namespace errors in my Entity Framework 4.1 model template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, code-generation, compiler-errors, t4

I have a T4 template to generate C# classes for the entities backing my `.edmx` model. The template starts with this header:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>
```

Attempting to build the project results in these errors

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Design' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'...
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EnvDTE' could not be found (are you missing a using directive...
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out than, based on a [VS Extensibility thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/aef36db4-379b-4d36-b3e2-c2ae252d79c3), the reason for the problem was
the Clarius Visual T4 extension. It reset this node in the `.csproj`
file to

```
<Compile Include="SomeModel.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>SomeModel.cs</LastGenOutput>
</Compile>
```

from

```
<None Include="SomeModel.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>SomeModel.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

The solution is to manually change the node to `None` in the `.csproj` file. Changing it
back via the Visual Studio properties editor for the `.tt` file *does not work*.
Finally, disabling the extension prevents this from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply **add needed assemblies** at the beginning of your `.tt` file; like this:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity.Design" #>
...
```